# Замена данных в существующем DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

В DataFrame есть список комнат от 0 до 19. Необходимо привеси его в соответствие.
Все данные с значениями комнат = 0 убрать из DataFrame, а все данные с комнатами > 4 включить, заменить на 4.

Пробовал несколько методов:

```
data["rooms"] = data["rooms"].drop(np.where(data['rooms'] == 0)[0])
data["rooms"] = data[data["rooms"] >= 4 ].replace((data["rooms"] >= 4), 4)
```

Второй:

```
rooms_data = data.drop(np.where(data['rooms'] == 0)[0])
def rooms_data_norma(row):
    if row['rooms'] >= 4:
        return row['rooms'] == 4
    else:
        return row['rooms']
```

[DataFrame - образец](https://pastebin.com/SjdGD89n)

В итоге, удалось уйти от 0 значений, но не удалось все, что больше значения заменить на необходимое в том же DataFrame.

Необходимо: в DataFrame должно остаться только строки, где изначально не было 0 и все что больше 4 должно замениться на 4.

Может быть есть метод легче и который сработает?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU внес ссылку на часть данных

Comment: ok, со входными данными определились. :) Как должен выглядеть результирующий DF?

Comment: @MaxU [То как должно выглядеть](https://pastebin.com/bhrjazU5)

Comment: Т.е. под убрать вы подразумеваете - заменить пустой строкой?

Comment: @MaxU нет, имею ввиду вообще исключить их из дата фрейма, удалить все строки которе имели "0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем входные данные:

```
In [146]: df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\SjdGD89n.txt")

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
    rooms
0       3
1       1
2       2
3       0
4       2
5       1
6       1
7       0
8       1
9       3
10      0
11      2
12      2
13      2
14      1
15      1
16     19
17      1
18      1
19      5
20      3
21      7
22      2
23      4
24      2
25      3
26      4
27      3
28      1
29      3
```

Решение:

```
df["rooms"] = df["rooms"].clip(0, 4)
df = df.query("rooms > 0")
```

Результат:

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
    rooms
0       3
1       1
2       2
4       2
5       1
6       1
8       1
9       3
11      2
12      2
13      2
14      1
15      1
16      4
17      1
18      1
19      4
20      3
21      4
22      2
23      4
24      2
25      3
26      4
27      3
28      1
29      3
```